# C# StringBuilder with Quotes (forJSON)

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have build a JSON string (to be posted to a web service), and I used the C# StringBuilder class to do this.  The problem is, that when I insert quotes, the StringBuilder class escapes them.

I am currently building the JSON string as such:

```
StringBuilder dataJSON= new StringBuilder();
dataJSON.Append("{");
dataJSON.Append("  " + Convert.ToChar(34) + "data" + Convert.ToChar(34) + ": {");
dataJSON.Append("  " + Convert.ToChar(34) + "urls" + Convert.ToChar(34) + ": [");
dataJSON.Append("  {" + Convert.ToChar(34) + "url" + Convert.ToChar(34) + ": " + Convert.ToChar(34) + domain + "/" + path[0] + Convert.ToChar(34) + "}");
dataJSON.Append("  ,{" + Convert.ToChar(34) + "url" + Convert.ToChar(34) + ": " + Convert.ToChar(34) + domain + "/" + path[1] + Convert.ToChar(34) + "}");
dataJSON.Append("  ]");
dataJSON.Append("  }");
dataJSON.Append("}");
```

However, the command:
`dataJSON.ToString();` results in the string:

```
{  \"data\": {  \"urls\": [  {\"url\": \"domain/test1.html\"}  , {\"url\": \"domain/test2.html\"}  ]  }}
```

Notice the escaped quotes? This is really screwing me up, because the server can't handle the slashes.

My desired (which posts fine to my server when I use PHP) *should* be:

```
{  "data": {  "urls": [  {"url": "domain/test1.html"}  , {"url": "domain/test2.html"}  ]  }}
```

Is there ANY way to get a string in C# to include quotes that will result in the desired string?

Many thanks!
Brett

Comment: Where are you seeing those?  In the debugger?

Comment: Yes, in the intermediate window. Could this be the problem? Would the intermediate window be adding the slashes?

Comment: That's not what is really returned

Comment: Your code works very well in my computer, I don't see the backslashes when I call ToString...

Comment: "Would the intermediate window be adding the slashes?". Yes, that's exactly what's happening. Add a watch for that value, and view with a Text Viewer, you'll see what's actually in the string, no escapes.

Comment: Why `Convert.ToChar(32)`? What's wrong with `\"`? I.e. `"  \"data\": {"`.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: He didn't want the `\\` escape character appearing in the output, I dare say the code above *evolved* from using the escape char to adding in the quotes as above.

Comment: @Binary: But the escape character *doesn't* appear in the output!

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I think Brett knows that *now* :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QuickWatch/Watch window will add the extra `\` in. If you view it in the Text Visualizer, you will not see them:

QuickWatch:

```
"{  \"data\": {  \"urls\": [  {\"url\": \"domain/path1\"}  ,{\"url\": 
    \"domain/path2\"}  ]  }}"
```

Visualizer (the actual output):

```
{  "data": {  "urls": [  {"url": "domain/path1"}  ,{"url": "domain/path2"}  ]  }}
```

The `\` indicates that the quotes have been escaped and will be included in the final string as you're expecting them to be. I.e. there's **nothing wrong** with your output.

*NB. I used `"\""` instead of `Convert.ToChar(34)` when I tested this.*

Answer (score 3):

You may have more luck using the [Newtonsoft.JSON library](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx), or alternately just escaping the slashes yourself as \" in your string literals instead of using Char(34).

```
dataJSON.Append(" \"data\": {");
```