# some problems with converting from StringBuilder to string

Tags: c#

I read response from google weather like this

```
using (StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(streamreader.ReadToEnd());
            sb.Remove(0, 21);
```

In debugger string looks like

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
```

but when I convert StringBuilder to string I've got

```
  <xml_api_reply version=\"1\">
```

It adds  `\` before every `"`. What's the problem?

Comment: you see the "\" in the debugger when you analyze the string?  Or you output the string and it has the \ in the actual output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# StringBuilder with Quotes (forJSON)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379262/c-sharp-stringbuilder-with-quotes-forjson)

Answer (score 2):

If you see the slashes in the debugger, it's not a problem: it's normal.

> The QuickWatch/Watch window will add the extra `\` in. If you view it
>   in the Text Visualizer, you will not see them:
>
> QuickWatch:
>
> ```
> "{  \"data\": {  \"urls\": [  {\"url\": \"domain/path1\"}  ,{\"url\": 
>     \"domain/path2\"}  ]  }}"
> ```
>
> Visualizer (the actual output):
>
> ```
> {  "data": {  "urls": [  {"url": "domain/path1"}  ,{"url": "domain/path2"}  ]  }}
> ```
>
> The `\` indicates that the quotes have been escaped and will be
>   included in the final string as you're expecting them to be. I.e.
>   there's **nothing wrong** with your output.

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379353/1220876

Comment: hm...So it doesn't cause `ArgumentException(Illegal characters in path)`...Strange.